# Wordpress Elementor: how do I keep a block constant among pages?

Tags: wordpress, templates, elementor

I'm using Elementor as page builder. My website has some sections which I want to keep the same among multiple pages, such as a "Latest News" section or a "Contact Us" banner at the bottom of a inner page.

For example a product page has:

```
Product Title
Product Description
Latest News
Contact Us
```

While a team page has:

```
Team Name
Team Members
Latest News
Contact Us
```

Is there a way to "centralize" the "Latest News" and "Contact Us" sections or blocks and keep them the same among multiple pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. This is a PRO feature, but you can create a saved template and then embed that centralized section anywhere on your site. There are multiple ways to do this, but I prefer using a shortcode.

See here >> https://docs.elementor.com/article/97-embed-templates